# covert conditional query in php to laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to change some php code to laravel but this are some condition to update , how can I implement them in laravel ? I want to write only update method to update but how can I implement this conditions

This are some php query that I want to convert to laravel

```
UPDATE products SET name="new Product" WHERE price=40 AND status=0

UPDATE products SET name="old one" WHERE price=100

UPDATE products SET price=0 WHERE status=2
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all create a Model in your application using

```
php artisan make:model Product
```

then all you have to do is using that model to query your way down to the result:

```
//add Product model namespace on the top
use App\Product;


Product::where('price', 40)->where('status', 0)
                           ->update(['name' => 'new Product']);

Product::where('price', 100)
        ->update(['name' => 'old one']);

Product::where('price', 0)
        ->update(['status' => 2]);
```

you can put as many where clauses as you like and you can pass any array to the update method. just update the array as you wish

and if you want them run at the same time:

```
use DB;
use App\Product;
use Exception;
public function update()
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        Product::where('price', 40)->where('status', 0)
            ->update(['name' => 'new Product']);

        Product::where('price', 100)
            ->update(['name' => 'old one']);

        Product::where('price', 0)
            ->update(['status' => 2]);
        $status = true;
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $status = false;
    }

    if ($status) {
        DB::commit();
    } else {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}
```

or you can write one line code to make it dynamic:

```
   $conditions = [
        ['price', 40],
        ['status', 0]
    ];
    
    $data = ['name' => 'new name'];
    
    Product::where($conditions)->update($data);
```

Comment: In this case if I have more condition i have to write a lot of update method I wanna write one update method and one method that can filter my database then I will update

Comment: You can always and in this scenario have to use transactions in case any of them failed, then all of them roll back and if not then all get's updated at the same time

Comment: DB::beginTransaction();   |     DB::commit();     |     DB::rollBack();   are for your purpose

Comment: Is it possible to write dynamic filter and then update?I wanna write dynamic

Comment: can you explain what do you need exactly?

Comment: Product::where($conditions)->update($data); and you have to create $condition array and $data array to make this works

Comment: I may have more than 50 conditional query like so , there for I have to write one dynamic update method that give selected row and then to select data I have to write dynamic filter method and the result of filter method should return selected data to update method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219918/discussion-between-mohammad-and-verjil).

Answer (score 1):

**use DB query to update your data.**

```
DB::table('products')->where('price', 40)->where('status', 0)->update(['name' => 'new Product']);

DB::table('products')->where('price', 100)->update(['name' => 'old one']);

DB::table('products')->where('price', 0)->update(['status' => 2]);
```

**Or If you want to update  data with model then use**

**`Use App\Product;` Top Of your code**

```
Use App\Product;

Product::where('price', 40)->where('status', 0)->update(['name' => 'new Product']);

Product::where('price', 100)->update(['name' => 'old one']);

Product::where('price', 0)->update(['status' => 2]);
```

Comment: It should help you to better understanding.. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: I just wanna write one update method and one method to filter then update , in this case I have to write a lot of update in update method , I cant write dynamic filter and update?